# Using the same name for multiples column in a large dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have created a large dataframe using 19 individual CSV files. All the CSV files have a similar data structure/type because those are the same experimental data from multiple runs. After merging all the CSV file into a large dataframe, I want to change the Column name. I have 40 columns. I want to use the same name for some columns, such as column 2,5,8,..should have "Counts" as column name, column 3,6,8.....should have 'File name' as column name, etc. Right now, all the column names are in number. How can I change the column name?

I have tried this code
newDf.rename(columns = {'0':'Time',tuple(['2','5','8','11','14','17','20','23','26','29','32','35','38','41','44','47','50','53','56']):'File_Name' })
But it didn't work

My datafile looks like this ...

[image]

Comment: Are you using Python/Pandas?  If so, then please edit the _tags_ under your question accordingly.

Comment: I don't think you can have same column name to multiple columns of the same dataframe. 

Why don't you concat the multiple dataframes this way
df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,df6,...etc])

And then give proper column names for the final df

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand it correctly, you wish to modify the name of the columns based from its content:

```
df.columns = [f"FileName_{v[0]}" if df[v[1]].dtype == "O" else f"Count_{v[0]}" for v in enumerate(df.columns)]
```

What this one does is to check if the column's data type is object where it will assign "Filename" in that element; else "Count"

Then add first column as "Time":

```
df.columns[0] == "Time"
```